# view hindi (Arabic) numbers in Firefox

Tags: firefox, localization, numbers

When viewing Arabic pages in Firefox, all the numbers are still Latin..  unlike in IE for example, where it shows the Arabic numerals (hindi) well for Arabic pages, and Latin for other pages..

I found a tweak online through about:config (bidi.numeral), but it changes all the pages for all the languages to one type of numbers only!

I am looking for a fix that lets me view the numbers depending on the page..  not fixed..

Comment: [Are you sure that everything is UTF8?](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: everything? I am talking about any html page or website..  when the format is Arabic it should read Arabic numbers like in Internet Explorer..  and when English it reads English..  In Firefox all reads as Latin.

Comment: So what you're talking about is not a problem with a website of yours or anything that has to do with programming? You're probably looking for  [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Common digits 0, 1, 2 etc. are distinct from Arabic digits ۰, ۱, ۲ etc. at the character level, so if a browser substitutes one for the other, consider it a bug. Please provide an actual example where that happens, for an analysis.

Comment: http://arabic.cnn.com/ under the red header to the right there is the date.  It reads in Arabic numerals in IE, but in FF it doesn't..  all websites read only Latin numbers.

Comment: I think digit substitution depends on your system locale. What is your system locale set to? On my machine the Arabic CNN page looks the same in FF and IE9: date shown with 0-9 numerals.

Comment: I think this question should be moved to superuser.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bidi.numeral works as described in [the documentation](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About%3aconfig_entries#Bidi). If you set it to 2, you will get Arabic numerals in Arabic contexts, meaning that if some digits occur in the middle of Arabic text (or any other right to left language I think), they will be rendered as Arabic digits. If the digits are at the beginning of the text or in the middle of none Arabic text, they will be rendered as the default digits [0-9].

If you set it to 3, all the digits in the browser will be rendered as Arabic numerals.